# Bluetooth mouse not working after reconnecting

Tags: windows-10, mouse, bluetooth, hid

My bluetooth mouse is not working after it lost connection to the windows 10 PC and connection is established again. To get the mouse working again, I need to unpair the bluetooth mouse and pair it again. Afterwards it is working working again.

The issue occurs after following events.

- PC is restarted
- PC is started after standby mode
- mouse is moved out of bluetooth range and moved into range again
- mouse is turned off and on again
- bluetooth on the PC is disabled and enabled again

The weird thing is following. Windows correctly states the state of the bluetooth mouse under "bluetooth devices". In case the mouse is powered off, it is listed as "paired". When I turn it on again, the mouse is listed as "connected" but not working.

What is the issue here and how can I fix it?

**Update:** Also the battery is no issue. It is a chargeable mouse and got fully charged now. And the battery stats are correctly displayed on the PC under "bluetooth devices" after the mouse connects automatically. Only the typical mouse functions are not working.

Comment: It will do the above if the mouse battery is low,  Try a new battery.

Comment: @John please see my update

Comment: I managed to get it working as expected meanwhile. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Perform following procedure.

1. Open device manager and "uninstall device" under Properties of the bluetooth mouse
2. Reboot the PC
3. Unpair and pair the bluetooth mouse again under the bluetooth options

Afterwards everything was working as expected for me.